# Can one upgrade the VSTO version used by Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsto

I have Visual Studio 2010 and I installed (re-installed due to new PC) it recently (this year).  I have noticed that the VSTO runtime is now up to Version 4.0.40820 but my version in Visual Studio in for example;

C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VSTO40\v4.0.Framework\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.dll

This shows version as the runtime v4.0.30319.

So I am wondering can I some how get Visual Studio to use the latest VSTO runtime version?

edit: My question was confusing as I had 2010 and v4 mixed up.  Please see my image of one VSTO reference.

So you can see with the image that the Runtime Version is 4.0.30319 which is at least a year behind the acutal runtime version.  And what does the Version 10.0.0.0 in this image mean?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the v4.0.30319 is the VSTO version? When I googled it I found .net version like that. The version is pretty low for VSTO. For example my Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version is 12.0.0.0 and thats targeting Office 2007, so vsto 4.0 should be 15.0.0.0.

Comment: Hi Mitjia thank you for replying.  You got me reading my question again and now I have fixed it.  But to reply directly to you comment you are talking about the PIAs which are what is needed for managed code to talk to Miscrosoft unmanaged code that Office is written in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can upgrade the VSTO runtime but I can give you some "lights" what the version means. 
The version 10.0.0.0 is a sign of VSTO 4 which is installed with Visual Studio 2010 Professional and above
If you see version 9.0.0.0 is a sign of VSTO 3 which is installed with Visual Studio 2008

[Here is some explanation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c21a8b4-40a1-48cc-b287-c9e678e0d082/how-many-versions-of-visual-studio-tools-for-office-vsto-are-there-and-what-are-the-differences?forum=vsto)